# Using SVN Team integration in Eclipse disables access from terminal

Tags: eclipse, svn, macos, version-control

I'm using Eclipse with Subversive SVN Team Provider 0.7.0.v20080425 as well as the latest update of Subversion installed on OSX 10.5.6.

My problem is that whenever I add a project folder to Eclipse enabling the Team integration it disables the SVN functionality from within the terminal throwing me the following error message :

> svn: This client is too old to work
>   with working copy '.'; please get a
>   newer Subversion client

Even if I first checkout a project via the terminal with OSX SVN client and thereafter creates a project upon the folder Eclipse seem to overwrite the settings.

It's quite painful as I have more control over the tasks thanks to the terminal and in the same time Eclipses integration is quite nice for simple actions as quick commits, adding files, etc.

Anybody a clue how to make it possible to work with both ? (i.e. How to stop Eclipse changing the required SVN version or making them work with the same version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of Subversive uses a newer working copy layout that comes with Subversion 1.5. Either upgrade the version of `svn` you're using on the command-line (I prefer [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)) or use an older version of Subversive that uses the 1.4-era working copy layout.

P.S. I find that [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) plays nicer with other tools than Subversive. YMMV.